# Android, Limit same button pressed multiple times

Tags: android

I have buttons in my app that do various things. A problem i am running into is that a button can be pressed multiple times before what that button does is enabled/processed/calculated.

Example

when i press a button { an integer should have 1 added to it unless it is at it maximum value.

when i press a button { a dialog should show (only once).

in either case if i press slowly i have no problems, but if i press rapidly the integer will pass its maximum or multiple dialogs will show.

Can someone point me in the right direction to deal with this.

Comment: I can see how multiple dialogs will show, but how can the int pass its maximum value? Aren't you testing before incrementing? Or is the incrementing being done on a separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you could simply set a boolean value when the button handler is entered to signify that the task is being performed.  If you enter the function and the value is already `true` then simply return (or just disable the button until the operation is complete).

I don't know a lot about android, and I don't know if you have the task running in a different thread or if multiple clicks are being queued up, in which case the boolean wouldn't help as it would all be happening in serial.  In that case, as I suggested earlier, just disable the button while the task is in progress (probably a good idea in any case).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest disabling is not that user friendly, i see the user is selecting button and has a lot of time in between before the next operation happens and tats why he ends up clicking multiple times. In this case as soon as soon capture the click you can show circular progress dialog , that shows user something is in happening and he wont be able to click button also.
Dismiss the dialog once you have set the counter 
or second case about to open the dialog                                                                   ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                        "Loading. Please wait...", true);                                                 then dialog.dismiss() once ur done